# JavaScript Cookie VS angularjs $cookies

Tags: angularjs, cookies

whats the difference between a cookie created using JavaScript and the one created using angularjs $cookies.

If I create a cookie using JavaScript syntax like mentioned below , cookie values are retained even when user refreshes the browser.

```
document.cookie = "username=smith";
```

Whereas when I use $cookies , cookie values are not retained when user refreshes the browser.

```
$cookies.FromPage = 'has value';
```

I was expecting that the values to be retained in $cookies also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) in angular > 1.3 you should use its methods `put(key, primitiveValue)`,  `putObject(key, objectValue)` and `remove(key)` to update the store and `get(key)` or `getAll()` to access its content.

Comment: What you said is correct , I have used older version syntax... that's the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @CleanCrispCode how about if I am using angular 1.3? I am running into this same issue.

Comment: @stecd I think you should post your own question then, but make sure you've read the module's documentation for your version [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.19/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) before